# Dynamic sequential identity column and conditional constraints?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

Hoping you guys can help me brainstorm some ideas for a roadblock I'm hitting at work.  I'll try to give as much info as I can here.

1) ProductSerialEnum - This is a table that contains serial number enums for various product types.  What it does is define the range of Serial Numbers a product can have.  New Types will be constantly coming in so here's a current sample

```
ProductTypeId   SerialPrefix SerialStartRange     SerialEndRange
--------------- ------------ -------------------- --------------------
1               2            2000000000           2999999999
2               1            1000000000           1999999999
3               4            4000000000           4999999999
4               3            3000000000           3999999999
5               501          5010000000           5019999999
6               500          5000000000           5009999999
7               601          6010000000           6019999999
8               600          6000000000           6009999999
...             ...          ...                  ...
```

2) The desired results

Products - This is table of product attributes which I'll shorten down to the important bits.

Here is what I'd expect this table to look like, but I'm having issues meeting all my success criteria.

```
ProductId   ProductTypeId   SerialNumber
----------- --------------- ------------
1           2               100000000
2           2               100000001
3           2               100000002
4           2               100000003
5           2               100000004
6           2               100000005
7           2               100000006
8           2               100000007
9           4               300000000
10          4               300000001
11          4               300000002
```

And so on...

My question is what is the best way to populate the Products table to work like the sample I posted above.

When a Product has to be inserted I'm provided a ProductTypeId and upon insertion I'm expected to generate a Serial Number as defined by the range in the SerialEnum table.

These Serial Numbers have to be insert in sequential order per Enum type as you can see in the example that I'm expecting. Them being sequential is absolutely critical, we can't burn any serial numbers because these ranges are the ranges we are allotted.

My initial thoughts are to generated an insertion SP that takes in the Product info with my critical ProductType then hold what the maximum serial number is for that product's serial range then simply insert the next value.

However the database receives a ton of concurrent traffic so my biggest worry is serial number collisions and skipping large range chunks due to concurrency or locking issues.

I've considered other options like potentially partitioning the table and messing around with IDENTITY columns and ranges, however with the product types increasing in scope so frequently I wouldn't  be able to keep up with continually running a partition scheme every time the product types change.

So to sum it up, every product insert in to the table must generate a unique and sequential serial number based upon the serial number ranges defined in the ProductType table without wasting serial numbers or causing errors due to concurrency issues.

If anyone has some experience or ideas I'd be super thankful if you could bounce them off me!

Comment: Why do your expected numbers start with 2 when ProductTypeID 2 has a range 10000000

Comment: in your desire result you show `ProductTypeId` 2 with `SerialNumber` starts from `2` ? Doesn't it suppose to starts from `1` ?

Comment: A couple of questions: What is the timeframe - are we trying to do an atomic operation, or can we write then update the serial? What about failures - if we have multiple updates happening, and one fails, what happens to that serial. And what about product deletions or does that never happen. You say you dont want to use up the ranges, does that mean you never-ever have gaps?

Comment: @LoztInSpace  you're correct, I made my example incorrectly, I'll update it

Answer (score 0):

> we can't burn any serial numbers

and

> However the database receives a ton of concurrent traffic

are mutually exclusive.  If you can't throw them away then you need to serisalise your transactions to make 100% it committed and allocated a number before moving onto the next.  If you use fast, sequences or identity then you may have gaps as the IDs will be allocated from a sequence cache.  Fail or rollback will cause a gap.

If you are permitted, you can always assign the serial numbers after the event in bulk.  This would entail having a fast, sequence or identity column for the primary key and insterting a blank serial number.  Periodically you scan the database for blank SNs and allocate them using ROW_NUMBER() based on the order (but not value) of the surrogate ID.

This will guarantee no gaps but there will be a time when not all products will have a serial number.

Comment: I thought about this, but if you use row_number() then if a product was ever duplicated then any later products would have their serial number change.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but I am suggesting you allocate it using this way and write it to the table as a new serial number using a combination of product type and the largest unassigned number in the range for that type.  I'm not suggesting the SN is some dynamic function of the product ID if that's what you mean.

Comment: I was talking about this bit `Periodically you scan the database for blank SNs and allocate them using ROW_NUMBER() based on the order (but not value) of the surrogate ID`. But it comes down to the use case - does it really matter if there a occasional holes or not. If the aim is not to run out of ranges then probably not.

Comment: This is something I've considered and is a potential option actually.  I need to check in with our CTO tomorrow though to see what an acceptable delay would be before the serial is assigned.

Comment: However I know the software engineers are going to take issue with any delay since the Serial Number generated will immediately(ish) need to be passed through to an API call for further processing...

Comment: Well as part of the process of assigning numbers you can push them out to the API as a separate step after the transaction has committed.  You would have to understand whether it matters if there is a delay of X seconds/minutes/hours between the product being "sort of" created and it being actually available for use (by virtue of having a S/N).  It may not even matter but that depends on your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming each range is sufficient to prevent rollover for the expected life of your app. Also, you can reduce the number of "burned" serial numbers by putting off their generation for as long as possible during the creation process, but I can't think of an effective method to eliminate it entirely. You will most likely have some gaps.

Do it in code, as a web service or whatever is most convenient to your app. Add a column to `ProductSerialEnum` called something like `NextAvailableValue` which starts out with the value in `SerialStartRange`. The code reads in this table on startup.

Your API defines an entry where the next available serial number is assigned, its copy is incremented and the procedure returns. The new `NextAvalableValue` will need to be persisted as a matter of course but that can be spawned off to take place whenever. That I/O then will not slow down the response time of the process.

You can do this by querying the database, of course, but an in-memory process can return thousands of serial numbers in the time it takes to perform one query.

There are many effective methods of keeping the in-database value updated periodically and persisting the changing in-memory values. These depend on your platform.

This is not strictly a database-oriented solution, but it is certainly faster and potentially much more robust than such a solution.